# Event "onClick" on treeview DHTMLX

Tags: javascript, html, dhtmlx

I have a treeview attached in a cell of a DHTMLX (pro) layout.

```
myTreeView = myLayout.cells("a").attachTreeView({
    xml:"/LRF/XMLWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/PROJECT/tree.xml"});
```

Now I'm trying to put an event "onClick" on this treeview in order to get just an alert on beginning.

```
myTreeView.attachEvent("onClick", function(id){
    alert("Item "+id+"was clicked");
    dhtmlx.alert("Item "+id+"was clicked");
});
```

But nothing hapened maybe there's an other way to do it if the treeview is attached in a cell but i don't find it.

If anyone can help me it'll be really appreciated.

Comment: [SOLVED] I changed the "onClick" event with an "onSelect" and it works !!

Comment: Don't edit your title to include "solved" tags. Add solution as an answer and mark that as your correct answer.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work - don't edit the word "solved" into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is my solution using "onSelect" instead of "onClick" event :

```
myTreeView.attachEvent("onSelect", function(id){
                    pid = myTreeView.getSelectedId();
                    dhtmlx.alert(pid);
                    });
```

With this event i can now populate my grid from my tree with adding :

```
myGrid.clearAll();
myGrid.load("/LRF/XMLWeb/ProcessDescriptor/descriptor/PROJECT/grid.xml");
```

That's it :)