# Loading Grid from DB - onSelect event

Tags: javascript, onclick, treeview, dhtmlx

I am having an issue loading my grid from an DB. My grid (2U) has tabs and loading from DB. I used the onSelect but it's not working for me. Any pointers will be appreciated.

***Note***: The `dhtmlx.alert(pid)` works fine I just can't load the grid. similar issue has been posted before. Thanks in advance.

```
tree.attachEvent("onSelect", function(id){
        switch (id){
            case "Athlete":
                pid = tree.getSelectedItemId(id);
            //dhtmlx.alert(pid);
               ath_grid.clearAll();
               var ath_grid = tab_ath.attachGrid();
               ath_grid.setHeader(["Name", "Address", "Phone Number"]);
               ath_grid.setColTypes("ro,edtxt,edtxt");
               ath_grid.setColSorting('str,str,str');
               ath_grid.setInitWidths('200,*,*');
               ath_grid.init();
               ath_grid.load("ath.php")
            break;
```

[Event "onClick" on treeview DHTMLX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51609261/event-onclick-on-treeview-dhtmlx/59843607?noredirect=1#comment105822398_59843607)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ath_grid.clearAll();` method just clears the data of your grid. You don't need to create a completely new grid object after that. You just need to load the new data.
Something like:

```
tree.attachEvent("onSelect", function(id){
        switch (id){
            case "Athlete":
                pid = tree.getSelectedItemId(id);
            //dhtmlx.alert(pid);
               ath_grid.clearAll();
             //var ath_grid = tab_ath.attachGrid();
             //ath_grid.setHeader(["Name", "Address", "Phone Number"]);
             //ath_grid.setColTypes("ro,edtxt,edtxt");
             //ath_grid.setColSorting('str,str,str');
             //ath_grid.setInitWidths('200,*,*');
             //ath_grid.init();
               ath_grid.load("ath.php")
            break;
```

If the data is not displaying after that please, make sure that your "ath.php" response generate a valid xml with the needed data.
If the problem still occurs for you please, provide an example of the generated dataset or a more detailed snippet/complete demo, so the problem could be reproduced locally.